# Object initialized with dictionary returns null

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdictionary

The return value of this method is returning null even though the dictionary being passed to is returning the correct data. In debug, I can see that dict is made up of 16 key/value pairs, but when it returns self, my object is returned with no data. I've looked at several examples and my code seems to be the same, but my method is not returning anything. 
Any help is greatly appreciated

```
#import "STHsCardData.h"

@implementation STHsCardData

@synthesize name = _name;

-(instancetype)initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary*) dict{
if (self = [super init]) {
    _name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
}
return self;
}
```

In this class, I initialize my STHsCardData object with the dictionary but the name property "newCard" object is always nil instead of the name of the card.

```
//Loop through data to get to each card object
for (NSDictionary *collection in data)
{
    if (collection.count == 0)
    {

        NSLog(@"array is empty");
    }
    else

        [setArray addObject:collection];
}
for (NSDictionary *set in setArray)
{
    for (NSDictionary *cardObj in set){
        STHsCardData *newCard = [[STHsCardData alloc]initWithDictionary:cardObj];         
        [cardArray addObject: newCard];
    }  
}    
return cardArray;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the data structure of the source of your data it's hard to tell exactly what's wrong. I suspect the issue is either in the nested-for loops you have for `setArray` and `set` - should there only be one loop there? Or the key is a different case such as `"Name"`, `"NAME"`, or that key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It's all but impossible to debug data-driven code like this without feeding it data and walking it through the debugger. Why not add a log statement to see what's going on:

```
-(instancetype)initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary*) dict
{
  if (self = [super init]) 
  {
    id nameFromDict = dict[@"name"];
    NSLog(@"In initWithDictionary, dict[@"name"] = %@", nameFromDict];
    _name = nameFromDict;
  }
  return self;
}
```